# How to keep original scale of width and height of a video in VideoView?

Tags: android

I add  `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` property to `<VideoView>` , and hope to keep original scale of a video, but I find  `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` don't work, and the video is deform.

How to keep original scale of width and height of a video in VideoView? Thanks!

```
  <VideoView

   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/LinerSeekBar"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

Comment: `VideoView` has no `adjustViewBounds` property

Comment: Thanks! but how can I keep the original scale of width and height of a video?

Comment: afaik you cannot do that, use `TextureView` instead

Comment: Thanks! Which Properties can I set in TextureView to keep original scale of width and height of a video , can I use the property android:adjustViewBounds="true" ?

Comment: set the transform matrix

Comment: have you got any solution for this...?